# Laptop touchpad not properly working

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, dell-inspiron

I spilled a cup of milk over my Dell Inspiron n5010 a few months ago. Since then I have problems with the touchpad. When I click the left button it's as I've clicked the right one.

Second, when I want to close a window, sometimes it doesn't change the button appearance and doesn't allow me to minimize/exit. Third, the right button doesn't work at all.

Can I fix this or not?

Edit: I forgot to say that when I move the cursor over a button and it doesn't allow me to close/minimize a window I must click `Ctrl+Alt+Delete`, then to click `Close`. Only then it allows me to close/maximize a window or something like that.

Comment: Does it always flip the click? Check if mouse setting has not been changed to left handed.

Comment: When i want to close a window, sometimes it lets me do it sometimes i must go over the button several times. It doesn't actually flip it, the right one never works. It's the same with the touchpad (when i click it's as I've clicked the right button). So, only the left one works, but not properly.

Comment: I guess its physically goofed up. Show it to the next door computer shop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident read the service manual and try opening and cleaning up. But I am not very hopeful that will fix it,  you might need to replace the components. Since it is new, it is better to get it serviced within the warranty period.

Comment: Recommend warranty repair